# Multiple random requests for Non-Existent URLs from a single IP resulting in 404s

Tags: webserver, ip, url

We sometimes get to see this behavior from a single IP address/logged in user -

There are a lot of hits on our server that have .png at the end of the URL which results in a 404 because we don't have any such URL nor a static file at this URL. Is this common across the web? Is there any extension that initiates this? or is the user intentionally trying to do this. What is the reason behind such random requests?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons for this:

- a misconfigured client that is sending traffic to your site meant for something else
- a mapping technique to try to find 'hidden' or non-obvious resources on your site
- sending known exploit strings to your server to see if your server has a vulnerability